# Moving Robinson game files/user profile from one android to another

Tags: applications

http://www.forumforpages.com/facebook/robinson-mobile/useful-tips/798367174/0

I tried the above but cannot find the below mentioned file which sound like what one needs to continue on playing the game at the level achieved on the old phone.  I so do not want to lose the levels and enjoyment and hard work put in on this!! :)

"UserProfile.json"
The file path suggested is there, but the Userprofile.json file is not there!

Comment: Related: [How does one copy all the data AND apps from one Asus tablet to another?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/30390/16575) / [Cloning an application with its full data store between devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/43885/16575). There were some more similar questions, but I currently cannot find them... For a more specific answer: is your device rooted?

Comment: I have just done a quick read of device rooted and probably not..I have not much understanding of this and don't know how to go about it!  Maybe that's why I can't see the file, is it a hidden one??

Comment: Yes it does exist on the SD card! as mentioned in the edited version of the question now!!

Answer (score 1):

My idea:
If you don't see the file, try to use another File manager which has the option to *show hidden files*. (sometimes it is impossible without root privilege)

And save the App to the SD Card rather than the phone memory, then try to copy everything. After moving, try to *re-copy* everything.

(*server sync not exists?* game support doesn't recommend anything for you?)

Comment: [ES File Manager](http://www.appbrain.com/app/es-file-explorer-file-manager/com.estrongs.android.pop) is such a tool that allows to show hidden files.

Comment: Could you just clarify for me, do I install this to the phone or to my computer as a file manager and do the copying and transferring via the computer??